# How can I fix this error TypeError: colormaps() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

Good afternoon, I am trying to replicate the Discrete distribution as horizontal bar chart of matplotlib documentation.
I copy and paste the code from matplotlib but a TypeError: colormaps() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
How may i fix it?

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    category_names = ['Strongly disagree', 'Disagree',
                  'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree']
    results = {
        'Question 1': [10, 15, 17, 32, 26],
        'Question 2': [26, 22, 29, 10, 13],
        'Question 3': [35, 37, 7, 2, 19],
        'Question 4': [32, 11, 9, 15, 33],
        'Question 5': [21, 29, 5, 5, 40],
        'Question 6': [8, 19, 5, 30, 38]
    }


    def survey(results, category_names):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        results : dict
            A mapping from question labels to a list of answers per category.
            It is assumed all lists contain the same number of entries and that
            it matches the length of *category_names*.
        category_names : list of str
            The category labels.
        """
    labels = list(results.keys())
    data = np.array(list(results.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
    category_colors = plt.colormaps('RdYlGn')(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.2, 5))
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())


    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
        rects = ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
                        label=colname, color=color)

        r, g, b, _ = color
        text_color = 'white' if r * g * b < 0.5 else 'darkgrey'
        ax.bar_label(rects, label_type='center', color=text_color)
    ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
              loc='lower left', fontsize='small')

    return fig, ax


    survey(results, category_names)
    plt.show()
```

And the error is

```
 line 38, in survey
    category_colors = plt.colormaps('RdYlGn')(np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))

TypeError: colormaps() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: `colormaps` is a dictionary like thing. You'll want to access values using `[]` not `()`. `plt.colormaps['RdYlGn']`

Comment: matplotlib docu [Discrete distribution as horizontal bar chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html) works for me. Your code gives the error you'r describing. Compare the two, probably a typo.

Comment: Hi @MagnusO_O unfortunately if I copy de code from matplotlib docu, gives me the error (in the same line 38): TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable. :(

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. @MYousefi If I change () for [] , the code now gives me this error (in the same line 38): TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That is odd. It works fine for me with `matplotlib` version `3.5.0` on `python 3.8.10`. There's also `matplotlib.colormaps` instead of `matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps` which you can try. Should be the same though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, what I did was upgrade everything, and now the code works. Thank you @MYousefi     :)